# Flutter: Common Dark and Light theme for bottomNavigationBar in ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-layout

I want to change unselectedItemColor and selectedItemColor color of bottomNavigationBar in both Dark and light theme mode.

I want to have a common theme of bottomNavigationBar, But In ThemeData there is no property for bottomNavigationBar theme.

Right now I am checking dark and light mode at run time like this,

```
var brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;

BottomNavigationBar(
 unselectedItemColor: brightness == Brightness.light
                  ? AppColors.colorHint
                  : Colors.white70,
  selectedItemColor: brightness == Brightness.light
                  ? AppColors.themeColor
                  : AppColors.themeColor.shade200,
);
```

But I Want to have dedicated BottomNavigationBar theme in my main.dart,
**Like I am declaring appBarTheme here, I want to declare BottomNavigationBar theme also for both Dark and Light mode.**

```
  ThemeData _buildDarkTheme() {
    final ThemeData base = ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          textTheme: TextTheme(title: AppStyle.titleDark)
      ),

    );
    return base;
  } 

  final ThemeData kLightTheme = _buildLightTheme();
  final ThemeData kDarkTheme = _buildDarkTheme();

   runApp(
      MaterialApp(
      theme: kLightTheme,
      darkTheme: kDarkTheme,
      ) 
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code at

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(),  
  child: new BottomNavigationBar(items: [  new BottomNavigationBarItem(),] ),

)
```

Comment: Yes I know, I wish we could have declare this in MaterialApp, also new keyword is optional and discouraged by the [Effective Dart guidelines](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-new).